# How do I align text and an array?

Tags: arrays, alignment

So I wish to have some left-aligned text and an array next to it. However, when I try, the array is slightly above the text (picture added below). Even `\aligned` isn't working. The text is within a proof environment if that is pertinent to the question. I have included the proof environment

```
\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=0pt, 
spacebelow=1pt,
headfont=\it,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=6pt,
qed=\qedsymbol,
headpunct=
]{mypf}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=Proof, style=mypf]{pf}

\begin{pf}    
\textbf{N2} (\textit{Positive homogeneity}) $||\lambda v||=d(\lambda v,\lambda 0)=|\lambda | d(v,0)=|\lambda | \cdot||v||.$  \vspace{0.1cm} \\
        $\begin{aligned}
        \left.\textbf{N3 }  (\textit{Triangle inequality})
        \right. \begin{array}{lll}
               ||v+w||=d(v+w,0)&\leq &d(v+w,w) + d(w,0)  \\
              &=& ||v||+||w||
        \end{array}
        \end{aligned}
        \end{pf}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably try with `\begin{array}[t]`

Comment: Off-topic: Please change all instances of `||` to `\lVert` and `\rVert`, respectively. (You will need to load the `amssymb` package.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't nest an `array` environment inside an `aligned` environment. Using a single `aligned` environment suffices.

For the following screenshot, I've also replaced all instances of `|...|` with `\abs{...}`, and all instances of `|| ... ||` with `\norm{...}`, where `\abs` and `\norm` are macros defined with the help of the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` directive of the `mathtools` package. Note also the use of the `[b]` positioning specifier for the `aligned` environment, which allows placing the QED symbol in the bottom row. Finally, I've created a macro named `\dist` to indicate the "distance indicator"; taking this route improves the spacing between, say, `\abs{\lambda}` and `d(v,0)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{\mathit{d}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    spaceabove=0pt, 
    spacebelow=1pt,
    headfont=\it,
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    postheadspace=6pt,
    qed=\qedsymbol,
    headpunct=
]{mypf}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=Proof, style=mypf]{pf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pf}    
\textbf{N2} (\textit{Positive homogeneity}) 
$\norm{\lambda v}=\dist(\lambda v,\lambda 0)
      = \abs{\lambda} \dist(v,0)     
      = \abs{\lambda}\cdot\norm{v}.$   

\medskip\noindent
\hspace{3.15em}%
$\begin{aligned}[b]
\text{\textbf{N3} (\textit{Triangle inequality}) }
     \norm{v+w}&=    \dist(v+w,0) \\
               &\leq \dist(v+w,w) + \dist(w,0) \\
               &=    \norm{v}+\norm{w}\,.
\end{aligned}$
\end{pf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose this variant layout, based on a single `alignedat{3}` for both lines. It uses the  `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=0pt,
spacebelow=1pt,
headfont=\itshape,
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=6pt,
qed=\qedsymbol,
headpunct=
]{mypf}

\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=Proof, style=mypf]{pf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pf}\!: \\[1ex]
$ \begin{alignedat}[b]{3}
& \textbf{N2}\ (\textit{Positive homogeneity})& \|\lambda v\|&=d(\lambda v,\lambda 0)\mathrlap{=|\lambda| d(v,0)=|\lambda | \cdot\|v\|. }\\[1ex]
& \textbf{N3 }(\textit{Triangle inequality}) & \|v+w\| & =d(v+w,0) & & \leq d(v+w,w) + \mathrlap{d(w,0)} \\
 & & & & & = \|v\|+\|w\|
\end{alignedat} $
 \end{pf}

\end{document}
```

[image]